how does a normal user unmount a flash drive mounted with pmount
How can I mount devices as a normal user? discusses how to mount a flash drive as a normal user.  How would I unmount that drive having mounted it with a pmount command?
Currently I am using Xubuntu 24.04.  As a regular user, I can mount but not unmount a flash drive.  From the GUI, it's demanding that super user password,  from the command line, the umount command responds must be superuser to unmount.

As you have failed to say what version of Ubuntu you are using I can not give you the exact name of the file program. I will just say using the default GUI file manager you can click on drive and choose to unmount.

In your question, you mention using the umount command - the linked answer says to use pumount - so which did you actually try?

Per @steeldriver, I was unaware of a pumount command.  I had tried the umount command.  The pumount command works.  If steeldriver rephrases his command as the answer - that's the one that I'll mark accepted.  Thanks

My 2-cent-comment: Thanks for the feedback, that you can use pumount. -- But I would like to add that you can probably use umount too (the main user has superuser privileges, via sudo), sudo umount /dev/sdx where x is the device letter, but this means that you must enter the user password, so it is more convenient to use pumount.

This turns out to be a duplicate of How can I mount devices as a normal user? which effectively says the pumount is appropriate to remove a pmount attached flash drive.
